# Getting ‘Stop running this script’ message in IE7

Tags: jquery, performance

I need to execute the below code on checkbox click

```
            for (i = 0; i < dropDownCtrl.length; i++) {

                $("#dropDownCtrl option[value='" + dropDownCtrl[i].objName + "']").remove();
           }
```

However am getting ‘Stop running this script’ message in IE7, due to large dropDownCtrl.length value.

Can anyone help me out how to integrate my code in the code mentioned in the URL given below,

http://www.picnet.com.au/blogs/Guido/post/2010/03/04/How-to-prevent-Stop-running-this-script-message-in-browsers

Please help.

Comment: What's the value of `dropDownCtrl.length`?

Comment: Why you want to stop **error** messages? You may use `for/in` instead.

Comment: The length is greater than 2000. How can I use for/in

Comment: From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) anyway I don't understand where your problem comes from. What's the problem of IE to handle just 2000 items? Do you have any reference for it or **exact error message you get**?

Comment: @Adriano IE7 doesnt support `querySelector`, which is what jQuery uses to make selectors fast. Therefore, it has to parse the string 2000 times, scan through all the elements on the page 2000 times looking for a `value` attribute with the right value (because CSS selectors are parsed right-to-left). That's a LOT of work and it's not surprising IE7 dies because of it. Whereas in my answer there's no need for such brute force.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol my +1, very good point!

Answer (score 3):

Step one: [Don't use jQuery](http://vanilla-js.com/).

```
var opts = document.getElementById('dropDownCtrl').options, lookup = {},
    l = dropDownCtrl.length, i;
// first use "lookup" as a quick lookup table - otherwise we'd have O(n*m) !
for( i=0; i<l; i++) lookup[dropDownCtrl[i].objName] = true;
// now we can do this in O(n+m), much better.
l = opts.length;
for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
    if( lookup[opts[i].value]) opts.parentNode.removeChild(opts[i]);
}
```

Ta-da! Should be much, much faster now.

Comment: in line 2  - : l = dropDownCtrl.length, i; is dropDownCtrl a variable? you declared?

Comment: Well considering you used it in your own code, I certainly hope it's declared!

Comment: However my control is a jQuery UI MultiSelect Widget, will it work for it?

Comment: I have no idea. I've never used such a barbaric tool. If it's well-designed, then it should work fine, however I just don't know. Try it and see.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using jQueryUI Multi Select control and CheckAll is causing the issue.
I have tried replacing .each() with the for loop in the **_toggleChecked** event which was causing timeout. After the change its working fine without any script errors.

```
this.element
    .find('option')
    .each(function() {
     //if(!this.disabled && $.inArray(this.value, values) > -1) {
        self._toggleState('selected', flag).call(this);
      //}
    });
```